# Create a new command that exactly mimics memoir's section* command without the spacing before it?

Tags: sectioning, memoir

I am using `memoir` and currently the `\section*` command does everything I want, except in some cases I don't want the space before it.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\begin{document}
\section{No Space, top of page}
\section*{Space}
\section*{No space above here, please}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example with spacing]

How can I make a new command `\qrr*` that is like `\section*` but without the prepended space? I don't want to accidentally change the formatting of other `\section` and `\section*` commands.

Comment: What would be the real use of this sectioning unit? Will there be real text before and after? In this case, which space should be suppressed?

Comment: The space before is what should be suppressed. Basically, I have multiple `mdframed` enviroments, one of which has this `qrr*` section in it, and I want them to run together (the formatting for the different `mdframed`s are different.

Comment: \usepackage{memoir} ???

Comment: Pay no attention to the man behind the curtain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure of this is what you want, but based in the comments to the question, I porvide this answer; `\qrr` is defined following `\section` in `memoir.cls` (the only change is `0pt` for the space before the heading and `6` for the level):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\qrr}{%
  \sechook%
  \@startsection{section}{6}%  level 1
      {\secindent}%            heading indent
      {0pt}%        skip before the heading
      {\aftersecskip}%         skip after the heading
      {\normalfont\secheadstyle}} % font
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{No Space, top of page}
\lipsum[4]
\section*{Space}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{mdframed}
\qrr*{No space above here, please}
\lipsum[4]
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

[image]